# Question related to the primorial of the 1000th prime number , 7919#.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

Suppose $m=7919$# which is the product of the first $1000$ prime numbers.

It is easy to find primes of the form $m\cdot n+1$ , where $n$ is a positive integer.

> But what is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $m\cdot n+1$ and $m\cdot (n+1)+1$ are both prime ? Sieving out small prime factors still lets many candidates remain , so I assume this positive integer $n$ exists. According to my calculations , we have $n\ge 3\cdot 10^5$ , but a doublecheck is welcome.

With the number theory tool PFGW this can be attacked using this input :

```
ABC2 7919#*($a+1)+1&7919#*$a+1
a:from 1 to 10000000
```

Since trial division does not accelerate the search much , has anyone a better idea how to attack such problems avoiding the extreme tough brute force ?

Update : The number $$n=681028$$ does the job , but I am not sure it is the smallest solution.

Comment: Why should anyone be interested in such pairs of primes based on that $7919$ primorial i.e. why is this not **numerology**?

Comment: Most of math can be traced to those who weren't afraid of numerology @BillDubuque . Fermat's little theorem can be attempted with pigeonhole principle and a fact about gcd. Why is that not numerology

Comment: If you call THIS numerology , than you can delete 90% of the posts on math stack exchange. Do you really compare this question with the ec-questions ?

Comment: I have no idea how to prove what $n$ might be smallest, but to find any example at all, might you consider $n$ being a Mersenne prime?